# Dynamic add MediaStream's into current.srcObject into a list of useRef for <video> [React]

Tags: reactjs

As MediaStream() needed to use `useRef` to work in video:

```js
const videoRef = useRef();
// ... some code until add MediaStream() to ref
videoRef.current.srcObject = event.stream;
// ... some more codes until the render function
return (
  <video ref={videoRef}></video>
)
```

What if I need multiple video streams? I can duplicate it like this.

**This works**:

```js
const VideoConferencing = () => {
  let [videosContainer, setVideosContainer] = useState([]); // to store video information

  // yikes i know
  const videoRef0 = useRef();
  const videoRef1 = useRef();
  const videoRef2 = useRef();
  const videoRef3 = useRef();
  const videoRef4 = useRef();
  const videoRef5 = useRef();
  // what if i need more videoRef in real time?

  // ... some more codes until defining each incoming stream to its ref

    if (num_streams === 0) {
      videoRef0.current.srcObject = event.stream; // event.stream is a MediaStream()
    } else if (num_streams === 1) {
      videoRef1.current.srcObject = event.stream;
    } else if (num_streams === 2) {
      videoRef2.current.srcObject = event.stream;
    } else if (num_streams === 3) {
      videoRef3.current.srcObject = event.stream;
    } else if (num_streams === 4) {
      videoRef4.current.srcObject = event.stream;
    } else if (num_streams === 5) {
      videoRef5.current.srcObject = event.stream;
    }

  // more codes until the render

  return (
    <div>
      {videosContainer.map(function (video, i) {
        return (
          <div>
            {video.videoIndex === 0 ? (
              <video
                ref={videoRef0}
                autoPlay
                playsInline
                controls
              ></video>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
            {/* ... so on and so forth ... */}
            {video.videoIndex === 5 ? (
              <video
                ref={videoRef5}
                autoPlay
                playsInline
                controls
              ></video>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
            {/* what if i needed more in real time? */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Defining it like this by copy and pasting is simply dirty, and it is not dynamic (what if the 7th stream comes in?). How can this converted to something more dynamic, where new streams received will create a new `useRef`, and then assign the stream into its `current.srcObject`?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to create an array of stream and render the videos dynamically using .map()

```
    const VideoConferencing = (arrayStream) => {
  let [videosContainer, setVideosContainer] = useState([]); // to store video information

  return (
    <div>
      {arrayStream.map(function (stream, i) {
        return (
          <div>
              <video
                ref={video => video.srcObject = stream}
                autoPlay
                playsInline
                controls
              ></video>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```